# Load WPF UI into MVVM application from plug-in assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on an application that uses a plug-in architecture to expand it's functionality. What is the best way to load WPF UIs from a plug-in?

I will have a listbox listing all of the available plug-ins. When a plug-in is selected, a WPF UI defined in the plug-in should be displayed in a `ContentControl`. The options I have thought of include:

- Require a `UserControl` to be created that implements a specific interface. I am thinking this would make it easy for plug-in creation. Implement an interface and you are good to go. My question with this method is how to dynamically load the `UserControl` into a `ContentControl`. Also, since I am using the MVVM design pattern it seems that a `DataTemplate` would be preferred over a `UserControl`.
- Allow a `DataTemplate` to be loaded from the plug-in. I believe this would require the plug-in to contain a XAML file named a certain way. My application would read the `DataTemplate` into my resource dictionary like shown [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/919613/918431)  I have seen quite a few questions similar to this, except they usually only need to load one additional, predefined assembly to get `DataTemplates` from. This problem would require any number of unknown assemblies to be searched for `DataTemplates`.

If I choose the second option, I think I could select the `DataTemplate` similarly to how [this answer describes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925239/918431)

Which method do you think is better? Or do you have a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did something similar like mentioned with `DataTemplates`. I used [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) to load plugins and then loaded a `Dictionary` with a reference to the `ViewModel` and `View` at startup. The plugin isbuilt using 3 main components.

**IBasePlugin.cs**

This simple interface allows us to create a skeleton for the plugin. This will only contains the very basics, as this is what we will use to `Import` plugins to our main application using `MEF`.

```
public interface IBasePlugin
{
    WorkspaceViewModel ViewModel { get; }
    ResourceDictionary View{ get; }
}
```

**Plugin.cs**

The next part is the `Plugin.cs` file. It contains all the properties of our plugin, as well as all the necessary references; such as to our `View` & `ViewModel`.

```
[Export(typeof(IBasePlugin))]
public class Plugin : IBasePlugin
{
    [Import]
    private MyPluginViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }
    private ResourceDictionary _viewDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Plugin()
    {
        // First we need to set up the View components.
        _viewDictionary.Source =
            new Uri("/Extension.MyPlugin;component/View.xaml",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }

    ....Properties...

}
```

**View.xaml**

This is a `DataTemplate` containing a Reference to the plugin `View` and `ViewModel`. This is what we will use for `Plugin.cs` to load into the main application, so that the application and `WPF` will know how to bind everything together.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyPluginViewModel}">
    <vw:MyPluginView/>
```

We then use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) to load all the plugins, feed them to our Workspace `ViewModel` responsible of handling the Plugins, and store them in an `ObservableCollection` that will be used to display all the available plugins.

The code we use to load plugins can look something like this.

```
var plugins = Plugins.OrderBy(p => p.Value.ViewModel.HeaderText);
foreach (var app in plugins)
{
    // Take the View from the Plugin and Merge it with,
    // our Applications Resource Dictionary.
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(app.Value.View)

    // THen add the ViewModel of our plugin to our collection of ViewModels.
    var vm = app.Value.ViewModel;
    Workspaces.Add(vm);
}
```

Once both the `Dictinoary` and `ViewModel` has been loaded from our Plugin into our application we can display the collection using for example a `TabControl`.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"/>
```

I also gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755476/how-to-add-controls-in-the-tab-item-programmatically-in-wpf-with-mvvm/8755865#8755865) as well with some additional details that you might find interesting.

Comment: Thanks! This will help a lot. I didn't think of simply including a `ResourceDictionary` in the plug-in. Also, I had no clue what MEF was.  I wish I would have discovered it sooner! Then I wouldn't have had to write my own (sub-par) plug-in architecture!

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but no matter what I do I get this error while trying to load the xaml file. `Could not load file or assembly 'MefTest.Plugin1.dll, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` The `Plugin1.cs` file is in a separate project with the `ClassLibrary` type.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are looking for has already been accomplished with Prism.  You define regions and then modules get loaded at runtime that may or may not have views for those regions.  This works if all your applications are built against the modularity concepts derived from Prism.  There are others out there, but Prism has this taken care of pretty extensively.

Comment: I will have to look deeper into Prism. I have just scratched the surface on Prism and only really have used it for `DelegateCommand` so far . Right now I am leaning towards the MEF solution because I like how simple the plug-in creation is. I think I would need to do some redesigning to use Prism.

Comment: I agree Prism is awesome. The only reason I went with my solution is because I wanted an easy way to integration already existing application. Since with this I could simply add a Plugin.cs and View.xaml to an existing application, and only make minor changes to add it as an plugin to my application.

Answer (score 2):

I use a similar approach to Fuji. The only difference is that I export the `ViewModel` and the `ResourceDictionary` independently from each other so they are still loosely coupled.

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin)]//i use metadata too
public class Viewmodel1 {}

[Export(typeof(IPlugin)]//i use metadata too
public class Viewmodel2 {}

[ResourceDictionaryExport]
public partial class MyResourceDictionary 
{
    public MyResourceDictionary ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In my plugin application I add all `ResourceDictionaries`.

app.xaml.cs

```
 [ImportMany("Resourcen", typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
 private IEnumerable<ResourceDictionary> _importResourcen;

 foreach (var resourceDictionary in _importResourcen)
 {
     this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
 }
```

For the sake of completeness

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ResourceDictionaryExportAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public ResourceDictionaryExportAttribute() : base("Resourcen", typeof(ResourceDictionary))
    {

    }
}
```