# Load a XAML file in a ResourceDictionary from a ClassLibrary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mef

I'm trying to make a simple plugin system in which a plugins are dynamically loaded from .dll files on application's startup and show up in the UI.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12204789/603200) seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. It uses MEF to load the plugins. I tried to create a simple project and follow the instructions. My solution has the following structure:

- MeftTest (contains main MefTest.exe, references only `MefTest.SDK` and not plugins)
- MefTest.SDK (contains the `IPlugin.cs` and `IPluginViewModel.cs` and the Engine.cs which loads the plugins from the application's directory)
- MefTest.Plugin1 (contains first plugin, references `MefTest.SDK`)
- MefTest.Plugin2 (contains second plugin, references `MefTest.SDK`)

#### MefTest.SDK -> IPlugin.cs

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    IPluginViewModel ViewModel { get; }
    ResourceDictionary View { get; }
    string Title { get; }
}
```

#### MefTest.SDK -> Engine.cs

```
public class Engine
{
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins { get; set; }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<IPlugin>> GetPlugins()
    {
        try
        {
            var folder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            //catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(folder));
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);

            var result = new ObservableCollection<IPlugin>();

            foreach (var p in plugins)
            {
                result.Add(p);
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //I get the exception here...
            var t = ex;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

#### MefTest.Plugin1 -> Plugin1.cs

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public class Plugin1 : IPlugin
{
    private MainViewModel viewModel { get; set; }

    public IPluginViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return viewModel; }
    }

    public ResourceDictionary View
    {
        get { return viewDictionary; }
    }

    private ResourceDictionary viewDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

    public string Title
    {
        get { return "Plugin 1"; }
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Plugin1()
    {
        //I get the error here. tried both of these, none of them work
        viewDictionary.Source =
        //    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MefTest.Plugin1;component/views/main.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        new Uri("/MefTest.Plugin1;component/views/main.xaml", 
        UriKind.Relative);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

however, I get the error `Could not load file or assembly 'MefTest.Plugin1.dll, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The `Main.xaml` file is in `MefTest.Plugin1\Views\Main.xaml` folder. Output type of the project is `ClassLibrary` and Build Action of the xaml file is `Page`.

PS: I tried to reference the plugin directly and add it without the MEF (`Plugins.Add(new Plugin3.Plugin3());`) and it still threw the same exception. So I don't think the problem is with the MEF part of the solution.

How can I fix this? Also, is there a better option to this approach?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the ResourceDictionary Source URI, but the missing assembly file or one of its dependencies. Does it work if you (just for a test) add a reference to the plugin assembly to your project?

Comment: @Clemens I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work either. (read the PS part at the end)

Comment: @Clemens exactly what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do it this way in an xbap application...to retreive distant xaml. Try to do the same with your local resourtce

```
private ResourceDictionary LoadDictionary(string source)
    {
        Stream streamInfo = null;
        ResourceDictionary dictionary = null;

        try
        {
            streamInfo = DistantManager.Instance.GetResource(source);

            if (streamInfo != null)
            {
                Uri baseUri = DistantManager.Instance.GetUri(source);

                dictionary = XamlReader.Load(streamInfo) as ResourceDictionary;

                dictionary.Source = baseUri;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            BusinessLogger.Manage(e);
            return null;
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
```

something like

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri(Mysource);
                dictionary = XamlReader.Load(XXXX) as ResourceDictionary;
                dictionary.Source = baseUri;
```

but on the other hand I do not understand why you want a ResourceDictionary as your plugin view...? just create the plugin user control ??

Comment: or the uri is the trouble because the link you gave is different 
        _viewDictionary.Source =
            new Uri("/Extension.MyPlugin;component/View.xaml",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Comment: What is `DistantManager`? And what should the `XXXX` be? If the uri is the problem, how can I fix it? To be honest your answer is more confusing than my question LOL

Comment: As i told, why not just creating the user control in the plugin (new MyUCPluginView(); ) instead or exposing  ResourceDictionary ??  DistantManager is special forxbap; but it open a ressource as stream and XXX is the stream = Application.GetResourceStream

Comment: If possible, give me an example of the code you'd suggest (meaning usercontrol)

Comment: take a look a this : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-WPF-Visual-3eb4e5dc

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't exactly what I wanted but I combined the concept with the MVVM.